# How to concatenate selected columns into one column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate selected columns and write the concatenation in a selected column.

For example, I have columns A, B, C, D, E, and each column has five rows. I'd like an InputBox to select maybe the entire column, or the first cell of the column, and then loop through all the remaining and put the results in another select range/first cell of the column.

If I select column A/cell A1 & column C/cell C1 and column F as the destination range, it will help me loop through A1 to A5 & C1 to C5 and put the results in F1(A1&C1) to F5(A5&C5).

I found something similar for a single cell, but does not do the looping.

```
Sub MergeCells()

    Dim xJoinRange As Range
    Dim xDestination As Range

    Set xJoinRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight source cells to merge", Type:=8)
    Set xDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight destination cell", Type:=8)
    temp = ""
    For Each Rng In xJoinRange
        temp = temp & Rng.Value & " "
    Next
    xDestination.Value = temp
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you be concatenating any number of columns?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want. It depends on the user to select any combination of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below. The concept is to go row by row and see if output is needed in that row by  using `Intersect` function. Also, check if there is anything selected for join in that row. Only the first column of the destination range will be written even if multiple columns are selected.

```
    Sub MergeCell2()

    Dim xJoinRange As Range
    Dim xDestination As Range

    Set xJoinRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight source cells to merge", Type:=8)
    Set xDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight destination cell", Type:=8)

     ' find 1st and last row

    Dim iRow1 As Long, iRowLast As Long
    Dim Rng As Variant

    iRow1 = 9999999
    iRowLast = 0

    For Each Rng In xJoinRange
        If Rng.Row < iRow1 Then iRow1 = Rng.Row
        If Rng.Row > iRowLast Then iRowLast = Rng.Row
    Next

    Dim rThisRange As Range
    Dim rDestCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As Variant

    For i = iRow1 To iRowLast
        Set rDestCell = Intersect(xDestination, Rows(i))  ' see if output is required in this row
        If Not rDestCell Is Nothing Then
            Set rThisRange = Intersect(xJoinRange, Rows(i)) ' see if anything is selected in this row
            If Not rThisRange Is Nothing Then
                temp = ""
                For Each Rng In rThisRange
                    temp = temp & Rng.Value & " "
                Next
                rDestCell(1).Value = temp  ' (1) to write only the 1st column of dest range
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```